# Ruby on Rails: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid can't cast ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I have this Rails code:

```
def newfood
  memberproduct = MemberProduct.new
  memberproduct.product_id = Product.where(:barcode_number => params[:barcode_number]).id
  memberproduct.expiration_date = params[:expiration_date]
  memberproduct.member_id = current_member.id
  memberproduct.save
end
```

I need the id of the product.
The 3rd line is wrong.

I have a `MemberProduct` table with a `product_id` field, an `expiration_date` field and a `member_id` field (current_member comes from `devise`)
I have a `Product` table with a `barcode_number` field and a `name` field.

I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in FoodController#newfood TypeError:
>   can't cast ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Product to
>   string: INSERT INTO "member_products" ("created_at",
>   "expiration_date", "member_id", "product_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
memberproduct.product = Product.where(:barcode_number => params[:barcode_number]).first
```

`memberproduct.product_id` is the database column where Rails stores the ID of the product associated to your memberproduct. Usually, these are not used directly; instead, the association name is.

So both of these work:

```
def newfood
  memberproduct                 = MemberProduct.new
  product                       = Product.where(:barcode_number => params[:barcode_number]).first
  memberproduct.product         = product
  memberproduct.expiration_date = params[:expiration_date]
  memberproduct.member          = current_member

  memberproduct.save
end
```

and

```
def newfood
  memberproduct                 = MemberProduct.new
  product                       = Product.where(:barcode_number => params[:barcode_number]).first
  memberproduct.product_id      = product.id
  memberproduct.expiration_date = params[:expiration_date]
  memberproduct.member_id       = current_member.id

  memberproduct.save
end
```

but the first form is more common. If you assign an object like `product` or `member` to the association, Rails is smart enough to ask the object for its ID and use it automatically.

Also, `Product.where` potentially returns multiple results. Since you only expect one, add `.first` to return only the first match.

Comment: Thanks, and what if I have to retrieve the id of this product? Will update question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you do have the product. If you really need the model ID, you can do what you do with `current_member.id` and add `.id` after `.first`.

Comment: It's probably a stupid mistake, but I have this code now:

    'product = Product.where(:barcode_number => params[:barcode_number]).first
    memberproduct = MemberProduct.new
      memberproduct.product_id = product.id
      memberproduct.expiration_date = params[:expiration_date]
      memberproduct.member_id = current_member.id
    memberproduct.save'
And it says undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

But thanks already!

Comment: Which one is nil, `product` or `current_member`? If it is `product`, that means that your `Product.where(:barcode_number => params[:barcode_number])` query did not find a product.

Comment: It didn't find a product, lol. I don't know why but somehow I wrote 0034000098279 as 34000098279. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on version of Rails, you should be able to:

Rails 3:
`Product.find_by_barcode_number(params[:barcode_number])`

Rails 4:
`Product.find_by(barcode_number: params[:barcode_number])`

You can simplify your action as so:

```
mprod = current_member.build_member_product(expiration_date: params[:expiration_date])
mprod.product = Product.find_by(barcode_number: params[:barcode_number])
mprod.save
```

Though you probably want to deal with validations and such (`if mprod.save .. else`)

Comment: I already found it but thanks for formatting the question! If I had more than 15 reputation I would certainly vote up, lol.

Comment: @xprise haha! No worries.